# Getting different results with arithmetic problems by following different approaches?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

The below question is from where my doubt had arisen.

**1st Problem:**

**Question:** A, B, C can do a job in 10, 20, and 40 days respectively. In how many days A can complete the job if he is assisted by B and C on every third day?

**Answer:**

A's one-day work = 1/10

B's one-day work = 1/20

C's one-day work =1/40

(A+B+C)'s one day work = 1/10 + 1/20 + 1/40 = 7/40

Work done in three days will be the sum of A's two-day work and (A+B+C)'s one day work.

A's two-day work = 1/10 * 2 = 1/5

Therefore, the work is done in three days = 1/5 + 7/40 = 3/8

3/8 part of the job is done in 3 days.

The entire job will be done by A in  = 3 * 8/3 = 8 days.

I decided to follow the same approach from the above question to another same kind of my own problem.

**2nd Problem:**

**My Question:** A, B can do a job in 11, 11/3 days respectively. In how many days A can complete the job if he is assisted by B on every second day?

**My Own approach to this Question [Correct me if I'm wrong]:**
A's one day of work = 1/11
B's one day of work = 3/11

So,
On 1st day, 1/11 work is done

On 2nd day, 4/11 work is done [Since B's work is also added on 2nd day]

On 3rd day, 6/11 work is done totally [Since 1st day's work(1/11) + 2nd day's work(4/11) + 3rd day's work(1/11)]

On 4th day, 10/11 work is done totally [Since 1st day's work(1/11) + 2nd day's work(4/11) + 3rd day's work(1/11) + 4th day's work(4/11)]

On 5th day, 11/11 work is done totally [Since 1st day's work(1/11) + 2nd day's work(4/11) + 3rd day's work(1/11) + 4th day's work(4/11) + 5th day's work(1/11)]

**So from this, we can know that it takes 5 days to complete the work by A. Simple right?
But when I follow the previous method from the first problem to this problem, it gives me different answers. I'll show it below,**

A's one-day work = 1/11

B's one-day work = 3/11

(A+B)'s one day work = 1/11 + 3/11 = 4/11

Work done in two days will be the sum of A's one-day work and (A+B)'s one day work.

A's one-day work = 1/11

Therefore, the work is done in two days = 1/11 + 4/11 = 5/11

So, 5/11 part of the job is done in 2 days.

**The entire job will be done by A in  = 2 * 11/5 = 22/5 days.
When I follow my own method I get 5 days which I think is the correct answer to my problem which is 5 days. But when I follow the previously given method, I get a different answer which is 22/5 days.
But both the 1st problem and the 2nd problem is of similar type except the numbers and some minor things are different.**

My doubt is If my own answer which is 5 days from the 2nd problem is right means then, Is the 1st problem wrong or the approach to the first problem is wrong?
But the 1st problem's solution is quite famous all over the internet.

Comment: how did you find that the amount of work done is not constant?

Comment: The first question is also similar. Both B and C work on every three days and not on daily basis

Comment: Noo...the first question is that they not work on every three days. They only work on the third day.

Comment: My second question is also that they only work on second day

Comment: The way I see it, the first problem's answer, the last step is dubious.  The way I interpret the problem is that the extra help provided by B and C would have occurred precisely on day $3$, on day $6$, day $9$ etc... and that by the end of the eighth day, $A$ will have had their assistance only for day $3$ and $6$ so far and the job will not have been completed yet.  The proposed solution attempts to average their combined work over the time period of three days which is good for getting in the ballpark or if we use an integer multiple of the time period number of days in the end.

Comment: @PeterForeman Does that mean their approach is wrong and my approach is correct?

Comment: @PeterForeman no... the "every third day" or "every second day" aspect is not in question here... it is heavily implied that the OP just phrased it or translated it incorrectly and intended $B$ to be working on the second, fourth, sixth, and so on days until the job is completed.  The issue here is in whether it was valid to have treated the amount completed over time as a single straight line, having used the average amount completed, or whether it was more correct to view it as the zigzag pattern like it really is.

Comment: @PeterForeman I really appreciate your time for answering. Maybe I'm poor at English. I didn't get why their approach is perfectly fine. Because they said every third day and my question is too on every second day.

Comment: @Allan Sorry their approach is wrong because the work done over $8$ days is in fact $$6W_A+2W_{A+B+C}\ne\frac83\cdot\frac{2W_A+W_{A+B+C}}3$$

Comment: Thanks Thanks guys. I appreciate you comments and for your answer too. Now I'm clear. But why famous websites like JavaPoint and TutorialsPoint are promoting this answer on their website If it's wrong.

Comment: A related but different problem...  "you are an artist who gets infrequent bursts of inspiration.  On the first day of the month you paint a million paintings.  On all other days in the month however, you do absolutely nothing.  Today's date is June 2'nd.  How many days will it take to have five paintings done?"  Here it becomes much clearer that with all of the work happening on the quick burst on the first day of the next month and absolutely no work happening until then, that the answer isn't going to be less than $1$ day since we specified that today's date is June 2...

Comment: It would have been 29'ish days since we need to get through the end of the month into the next month.  On the other hand, if we were told that today was July 1st, then we would be good... it would have taken much less than a day.  Now... consider the problem where we didn't tell you what day of the month it was when we made the request for more paintings... one might say that since our painter paints some $35$ thousand paintings a day *on average* (*even though work only actually occurs on one day a month by painting a million at a time*) that this might be a useful number to communicate

Comment: The way I see it, the proposed answer for the first problem is a correct method and answer for a different problem or at least a different interpretation of the first problem... where $A,B,C$ have *many* jobs to complete, not just the one, and our job we are interested in is somewhere in the middle and we don't know where in the cycle it will fall.  A more correct answer in that scenario might be "between 7 and 9 days" but they went with a sort of average answer of "an average of 8 days"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JMoravitz suggests in the comments the provided approach for question $1$ is not usually valid. The method assumes that the work done during any given day is constant and is given by the average work done during the period after which the working pattern repeats. But this not true as you found using the valid method you suggest. The suggested method is only valid if it's the case that after an integer multiple of this working period the job is done. This is because the average work done over every day considered would be equal to the periodic average in this case.